# React.js and Scrolling SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, react-router

I am beginning my react.js journey, and my goal is to create a single page application where the top navigation links scroll to the appropriate section on the front page like [THIS SITE](http://www.adventuresinwebdesign.com/samples/anchors/blog/).

So far, My application implements React.js and React-Router, and nests the link components within the front page. What I am struggling with is the correct implementation, to alter this code, in order to get the outcome shown in the link above. There are many SPA tutorials out there, but I have yet to find a current one that addresses my particular scenario using React.js+React-Router. Would anyone know a clean way to do this? or maybe a recent tutorial that walks one through the process?

Below I will list some relevant code to help guide the responses for a solution (or recommendation).Thank you in advance for any responses that I do receive.

Very Respectfully, 
Kama

client.js

```
    const app = document.getElementById('app'); 
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="AboutUs" component={AboutUs}></Route>
            <Route path="OurMission" component={OurMission}></Route>
        </Route>

    </Router>,

    app);
```

Layout.js

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { location } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav location={location}/>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
        <Header />
            {this.props.children}
            </div>
            </div>
          <Footer />
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Haki</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="client.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a cool lib that allows you to track the position of components (https://github.com/gilbox/react-track).  What's your reasoning behind using a router?  Could you not just have buttons that when clicked use the lib I linked and then do a page scroll to the appropriate location?  Or you could consider the good old native anchor tags :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I followed [This Tutorial](https://codeplanet.io/how-to-make-a-single-page-website/) to get the navigation links to go to other portions of the page. Instead of using this.props.children to pass the components to the layout.js file, I just added each of the components I want on the single page like below:

```
return (
      <div >
        <Nav location={location}/>
        <div class="container" style={layoutStyle}>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
        <Header />
            <Home />
            <Mission />
            <AboutUs />
            </div>
            </div>

      </div>
          <Footer />
      </div>
    );
```

Next, I changed the Nav bar links from react-router Links to anchors, as the tutorial explains.

To get smooth scrolling working, I used the Javascript file found [HERE](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/smoothscroll/#p4).